# Xamarin for android crashes on VM

Tags: android, xamarin, crash

I am completely lost.
It has been 2 days of trying after countless uninstall and reinstall just to get xamarin working.

I am trying to compile for android using xamarin running on Visual Studio 2015.
Compiling against Android 7.1 Nougat, running on KitKat 4.4 VM, it crashes right at startup, both debug and release.

Since i am new, i have no idea where to look at and seeking for help.

Comment: Run in debug mode, what is the exception details when it crash?

Comment: Please include a full diagnostic build error log.